# Is it bad practice to have a an ajax that returns JSON or HTML based on its success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an jQuery ajax function that responds with HTML in the call fails. If the call is successful it responds with JSON: `{"result":true}`

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.RESULT === true) {
                window.location.replace(baseUrl);
            } // else do something else and show errors
        }
    });
```

Firefox will not recognize the result in JSON, however, since the dataType is set to 'html'. I tried leaving it blank, and that didn't work. Is there a work around, or is it bad pratice to return two things?

It's for a registration form. I'm returning HTML because it's easier to show the user validation (server side) errors, while if the registration is successful I redirect them.

Answer (score 6):

I think an AJAX call should always return data in the same format. It is not good practice to return HTML only if the call fails. You may always return a JSON response with a **status** parameter that can be **success** or **error**, and a **content** parameter which is the HTML response.

Answer (score 5):

It is bad practice returning two different formats of data. Consumers of the service will not know what to expect, and it is also bad practice to vary the format across a related group of services (although some exceptional scenarios justify it)

In your case :

What you can instead do is to return JSON all the time, and in the case of errors return JSON in this format :

```
{
   "errorsHtml" : "<div class='errors'>...</div>"
}
```

And you can also leverage the HTTP Status Code headers to signify the state of the server, for example status 500 is server internal error. You can handle different status codes like this :

```
 $.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a bad practice, though not the end of the world. I'd rather call it "a hack". The status of the request should be based on response code (200 - OK, 40x content error, 50x server error).

Answer (score 2):

Dont specify datatype -
If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response

Specify multiple values is fine and allowed -
multiple, space-separated values: As of jQuery 1.5, jQuery can convert a dataType from what it received in the Content-Type header to what you require. For example, if you want a text response to be treated as XML, use "text xml" for the dataType.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    dataType: 'html json',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.RESULT === true) {
            window.location.replace(baseUrl);
        } // else do something else and show errors
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - check out the datatype description.

Comment: This does not mean server can return whatever it wants - In your case the return data is always converted to JSON even if it is in HTML and will not work when the server actually returns HTML in once case and json in another case

Comment: surely it does not mean server can return anything, but it is still fine.

Comment: You edited your answer and have told jquery to convert json into html, in other words even if content type is text/html jquery will treat it as json data. Good, now what happens when server returns json and clientside also wants json, for a call? However thanks for sharing this I did not know such a feature existed in jquery

Answer (score 2):

Good practice is returning the type of data that was **requested**. It's as simple as that. Sending data inconsistently may work for the short-term, but you'll end up with long-term maintainability problems when you've forgotten why you decided to return JSON in one situation and HTML in another.

There are many ways of requesting data, my personal favorite is a RESTful request implementation. There are many ways of implementing a RESTful system.

If you're going to make a request to `www.example.com/cars` you'll probably get a list of cars, but there's no good way for the server to know *how* you want that list of cars formatted.

A simple way of specifying what you want is to add a suffix: `www.example.com/cars?type=HTML` could be descriptive enough to notify the server what type of data you want…

Wouldn't it be convenient if there was a way to specify what type of data you expect to receive back from a server *without* polluting the query-string?

It turns out there is a way…file extensions: `www.example.com/cars.html` is very specific to what type of data should be returned, and you wont be confused in 6 months when you need to track down that bug, because you'll know that the client-side request is *expecting* HTML.

`www.example.com/cars.js` or `www.example.com/cars.json` can return a different type of data and you'll never be confused as to what the request should be returning to the client.

The best part of using a RESTful implementation is that you can throw your request errors out as HTTP status codes. Malformed request? send out a `400` error. Incorrect permissions? send out a `403`.

Bind an error handler to the AJAX request, and you'll be able to easily differentiate between the "success" JSON that gets returned and the "error" JSON.

If you *really* want HTML when JSON is expected, just JSON encode it in an object as `{"error":"your html <strong>here</strong>"}`